# Mean of all means of subsets of data differs from overall mean

Tags: r

I have a large data set which looks like so:

```
str(ldt)
 data.frame':   116105 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ s      : Factor w/ 35 levels "1","10","11",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PM     : Factor w/ 3 levels "C","F","NF": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ day    : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ block  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ item   : chr  "parity" "grudoitong" "gunirec" "pirul" ...
 $ C      : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE ...
 $ S      : Factor w/ 2 levels "Nonword","Word": 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ R      : Factor w/ 2 levels "Nonword","Word": 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ RT     : num  0.838 1.026 0.93 0.553 0.815 ...
```

When I get means by factor from this data set, and then get the mean of those means it's slightly different from the mean of the original data set. It's different again when I split it into more factors and get the mean of those means. For example:

```
mean(ldt$RT[ldt$C])
[1] 0.6630013
mean(tapply(ldt$RT[ldt$C],list(s=ldt$s[ldt$C], PM= ldt$PM[ldt$C]),mean))
[1] 0.6638781
mean(tapply(ldt$RT[ldt$C],list(s=ldt$s[ldt$C], day = ldt$day[ldt$C], item=ldt$S[ldt$C], PM=ldt$PM[ldt$C]),mean))                
[1] 0.6648401
```

What on earth is causing this discrepancy? The only thing I can imagine is that the subset means are getting rounded off. Is that why the answers are different? What's the exact mechanic at work here?

Thank you

Comment: Are there NA values in your data? You may show the output of: sapply(ldt, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))    and    head(ldt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mean of means is not the same as the mean of all numbers.

Simple example: Take the dataset

```
1,3,5,6,7
```

The mean of 1 and 3 obviously is 2, the mean of 5,6,7 is 6. 
The mean of the means therefore would be 4.

However, we have 1+3+5+6+7 = 22 and 22/5 = 4.4.

Thus, your problem is on the mathematical side of your calculation on not with your code.
To overcome this problem you would have to use the weighted mean, e.g. weight the summands of the outer mean with the number of values in each group, divided by the total number of observations. In our example:

```
2/5 * 2 + 3/5 * 6 = 4.4
```